# Stretch menu items horizontally Bootstrap 4 Flexbox

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, sass, flexbox

I am have an absolute positioned block with a menu inside (3 links).

The markup of my header and menu is:

```
<header id="header" class="header d-flex justify-content-center align-items-end">  
  <div class="my-block">
    <div class="container row">
        <div class="col-md-8 offset-md-2">
        <nav class="nav nav-pills flex-column flex-sm-row p-2">                  
          <a href="#" class="flex-sm-fill text-sm-center nav-link">Link 1</a>               
          <a href="#" class="flex-sm-fill text-sm-center nav-link">Test link 2</a>
          <a href="#" class="flex-sm-fill text-sm-center nav-link">Another link 3</a>
        </nav>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

How do I stretch the menu-items horizontally, so it's fills up totally the width of my `<div class="col-md-8 offset-md-2">`?

Comment: With `flex: 1` on `nav` ? ... or/and its children

Comment: That worked thanks! With `align-items-end` I align the menu-block `<div class="my-block">` vertically to the bottom of the `<header>`. But I don't want it to be totally on the bottom. I want some margin between the menu-block and the header on the bottom? How do I do that in combination with flexbox?

Comment: Wouldn't a `padding-bottom` on `my-block` fix that? .... updated my answer with such padding

Comment: That worked. Thanks. But in your example below the 3 buttons are not stretched to the width of the green block? And how do you give the 3 buttons the same width? Than I can except your answer. Thanks

Comment: meez, check the answers, give flex:1 to `nav` `a`'s and justify that.

Comment: @Syden I have now a second block in the same header. The first menu-block I want to position absolute and align left-top. The second menu-block I want to position absolute and horizontally center and on the bottom of the header (`.justify-content-center` and `.align-items-end`). Can I mix multiple aligning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```css
nav {
  border: 1px solid lightgray;
  flex: 1;
  justify-content: center;
}
.my-block {
  flex: 1;
  border: 1px solid gainsboro;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}
nav a {
  border: 1px solid green;
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<header id="header" class="header d-flex justify-content-center align-items-end">
  <div class="my-block">
    <div class="container row">
      <div class="col-md-8 offset-md-2">
        <nav class="nav nav-pills flex-column flex-sm-row p-2">
          <a href="#" class="flex-sm-fill text-sm-center nav-link">Link 1</a> 
          <a href="#" class="flex-sm-fill text-sm-center nav-link">Test link 2</a>
          <a href="#" class="flex-sm-fill text-sm-center nav-link">Another link 3</a>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```